# How mvc works in Zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-db, zend-studio, zend-db-table

Thanks for previous replies..

I am trying to print Hello_world using zend framework. I wrote php file in model folder and return string value as a "Hello_world". In controller i access  the value of PHP like this
`$value = new TextReturner();
        $this->view->setValue = $value->hello_world();` . i dont know how to access the value from controller to the view php file. I am new to zend framework. I already go through the outline structure of zend framework, i dont know how to access through codings. If anyone have idea of how to print hello_world through MVC pls guide me.

Comment: try to set in Controller $this->view->value = 'Hello world';
and to print that in view file, if it works, then the problem is in model file...

Comment: Are you autoload your models ?

Comment: @tasmaniski you are right, when i give $this->view->value = 'Hello world'; its is working fine. what is auto load..??  i am new to this topic, pls guide me. why my model is not working..

Comment: If you're unsure of how to use Zend Framework and you're new to it I'd recommend reading the [Quickstart guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use class $value = new TextReturner(); but your controller doesn't see that class.

Set this in your Bootstrap file that will help:

```
protected function _initAutoLoad() {
    // Add autoloader empty namespace
    $autoLoader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(
            array(
                'basePath'      => APPLICATION_PATH,
                'namespace'     => '',
                'resourceTypes' => array(
                'model'         => array(
                        'path'      => 'models/',
                        'namespace' => 'Model_'
                    ),
                ),
            )
    );
    return $resourceLoader;
}
```

This will be autoload all of your model class.

Comment: Thank you, i paste the above Autoload to my booststrap, but nothing is happened. again i am getting blank screen instead of printing Hello world

Comment: How are you called the Model class ? 

Giv name like this: Model_YourClass;

and then in Controller: new Model_YourClass();

Comment: Or just set in controller: 
include(APPLICATION_PATH.'/models/name_of_file.php');

And you can use model class...

Comment: Note that if you give name of model file MyModel.php you must give name of class Model_MyModel{}

Answer (score 0):

in view you can access your variable like this:

```
<?php echo $this->setValue;?>
```