# Trying to Create An Object in ZF but gives Application Error

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am New To Zend Framework. However while go through several tutorials I created a model file user.php where I created a class user extends `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract` and when i create an object of that class in my controller file it gives the application error as follows:

> Fatal error: Class 'User' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/hello_zend/application/controllers/ShowketController.php on line 17

Comment: in what folder did you create the model file?

Comment: If you're using the latest Zend Framework version. The class should be called `Application_Model_User` and the file path should be `application/models/Users.php`. Mind that if you're extending the table abstract you should use plural Users, User would be the row class for Users.

Comment: First you have to rename file user.php to User.php. 
if that class is in the folder Model, give the class name like this: class Model_User { ... } [ or Application_Model_User as markus says]

Answer (score 0):

You have to load file where the class User is, or autoload all model class.

How to do that, You will find answer here:

[How mvc works in Zend framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525165/how-mvc-works-in-zend-framework/7525933#7525933)

Comment: Its not working I tried those things but it gives some errors as    Application error
Exception information:

Message: No adapter found for Model_User

Comment: can you copy/paste your model class pls ?

Comment: Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($dbAdapter); // $dbAdapter = your Zend_DB instance